# MongoDB: how can I find and merge array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

I'm trying to find a specific ID in my document and then merge an array to the existing one, for example if I have this array stored in db.friends:

```
["12","13","14"]
```

and I send this array: `["12","16","18"]`, db.friends should contain: `["12","13","14","16","18"]`

I'm using underscore library, but I'm not sure I have to (maybe "aggregate" in mongoose?)

Here is what I did, can you tell me where am I wrong?

```
function saveFollowers(req, res) {
 var friends = req.body.friends; // the new array to merge ["54aafe9df4ee360300fc94c7"];

 User.findOne({_id: req.user._id}).exec(function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
          res.jsonp({error: "Error fetching user info"})
      } else {
        friends = _.extend(friends, user.friends); //user.friends=existing friends we have in db
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) { res.jsonp({error: "Cant save"}); }
            console.log("Friends NOW:"+JSON.stringify(friends)); //Here I don't see the merge, also, I can't see it in mongo db.
            res.jsonp("success");
        });
        }
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current implementation, you haven't actually modified the friends key in the returned user object. So rather you can use the **[`union`](http://underscorejs.org/#union)** method as

```
user.friends = _.union(friends, user.friends); //user.friends=existing friends         
user.save(function (err) { .. }
```

Or with ES6 using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for concatenating the array and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for creating a distinct set of elements:

```
user.friends = [...new Set([...friends ,...user.friends])];
user.save(function (err) { .. }
```

Another alternative is using the aggregation framework, you could utilize the **[`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/)** operator:

```
function saveFollowers(req, res) {
    var friends = req.body.friends; // the new array to merge ["54aafe9df4ee360300fc94c7"];

    User.aggregate([
        { "$match": { _id: req.user._id } },
        { 
            "$project": {
                "friends": { "$setUnion": [ "$friends", friends ] }             
            }
        }
    ]).exec(function (err, results){
        if (err) {
            res.jsonp({error: "Error fetching user info"})
        } else {
            User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, 
                { "$set": { "friends": results[0].friends } }, 
                { "new": true },
                function (err, user) {
                    if (err) { res.jsonp({error: "Cant save"}); }
                    console.log("Friends NOW: "+ JSON.stringify(user.friends)); 
                    res.jsonp("success");
                }
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you chridam, you made my day! (I used your second function, and it just works).. :)